# Where to find javascript console for tvos in xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

Where do I find the console output for tvos javascript in xcode or the sim? 
The answer is probably trivial, but I have not been able to figure it out.
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see the output at the bottom of Xcode. Click on the triangle at the left side, if it is hidden

[image]

Comment: I still can't see javascript console output in this window

Comment: This is not a javascript console. This is only the app console. Look at the answer from Geoff Hensley

Answer (score 7):

To see a full console (for things like console.log) for JavaScript, open up Safari and after you've built your app inside XCode, click Develop > Simulator and you'll be able to see a console of your app.

Comment: this worked for me, but only after closing both xcode and safari, then starting safari first, afterwards launching xcode and simulator